# Java Applet: What is the usage of Init(), Start(), Stop(), and Final()?

Tags: java, applet

Can we only have Start() and Stop() instead?

Any one know?

Comment: A Java applet does not have methods called “Init”, “Start”, “Stop”, and “Final”. Please use the real names. (And read the documentation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to implement init() and destroy() if you don't need to, they're there as hooks if you need them.

The [javadoc is very clear](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#destroy%28%29) on what you should and shouldn't implement.